# Bootmetro framework, issue with alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-metro

So I have been working with the [bootmetro](http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/) framework and I am getting an aggravating problem, the bootmetro comes with a [carousel](http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/javascript.html#carousel) and a [scrollspy navbar](http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/javascript.html#scrollspy).

I tried putting the carousel at the top of my page but for some reason the caption would spread from one side to the other because the width is set to auto in the css but the image would not.

I decided against doing that anyway and went for a side by side method, I have a demo of what I am trying to achieve [here](http://garrithgraham.azurewebsites.net/AboutMe.aspx) if you notice the carousel is not aligned correctly at the top with the project navbar.

[image]

Does anyone know how I could fix this, bear in mind I can’t play with the image css of the carousel as it is tied to everything else on the site? If I change them then the images in the home page go nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because you're using a table for your layout. Using tables for layout purposes is not a best practice. Anyways, to be consistent you should use bootstrap native scaffolding http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html instead.

Try to remove your table and use the folowing markup:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span4">
<!--Carousel goes gere -->
</div>
<div class="span4">
<!--Text and menu goes here -->
</div>
<div>
```